# I am getting django database connection error

Tags: django

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'student',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'pooja',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'
    },
}
```

Exception IS:
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

I am using mysql database I am getting above exception in django while migrating model to the database please let me know what is the error what i ma doing wrong here.
thanks you for your reply

Comment: Are you sure your settings are correct? Do you have MySQL installed and an account/DB with those details, using that password?

Comment: Isn't it `DATABASES = {}` ?

Comment: i used DATABASES = {} but it gives me jango.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET SESS
ION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED' at line 1")                    this Excetpion

Answer (score 1):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'student',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'pooja',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'
    },
}
```